# Is it right to say “This group has been created …?”

Tags: tense

Which question is right?

> 1- This group (a WhatsApp group) was created to enable its members to buy and sell … .
>
> 2- This group has been created to enable its members to buy and sell … .

Taking into consideration that this WhatsApp group is still working.

Comment: The creation was at a point in time. No need to use the PF.

Comment: Whether to use past tense or present perfect almost always depends on the context (e.g. the tense of other nearby verbs), but you don't give any context.

Answer (score 1):

Either option is correct. The creation of the group was a distinct event that happened one time in the past; the group is not in a continuous state of *being created*.

I would lean towards using "was created" as it is less wordy.

Answer (score 0):

Both fragments appear correct, and they have the same meaning, because creation is normally a singular process.

With a repeatable process, comparing sentences such as "The team was defeated" and "The team has been defeated", there is a difference in meaning. The first is used to refer to a specific occasion. The second is saying that it has occurred, but not necessarily every time the team played.